# Converting an array of ones and zeros to a binary variable

Tags: php, arrays

I'm writing an application in PHP which needs to take an array of ones and zeros of arbitrary length and convert it to a binary variable (to be stored in MySQL BINARY field). I also need a function to reverse this process.

What I'd like to end up with:

```
$bits = array(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1);
$bin = bits2bin($bits);

bin2hex($bin); // returns "5D"

$bits = bin2bits($bin); // = array(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1);
```

I have written the following two functions, which work for my needs:

```
function bits2bin($bits) {
    $binarystring = implode($bits);
    $bytes = str_split($binarystring, 8);
    $hexstring = '';
    foreach($bytes as $byte) {
        $hexbyte = dechex(bindec($byte));
        $hexbyte = str_pad($hexbyte, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $hexstring .= $hexbyte;
    }
    return $binary = pack('H*', $hexstring);
}

function bin2bits($binary) {
    $hexbytes = unpack('H*', $binary);
    $bits = array();
    foreach(str_split($hexbytes[1], 2) as $hexbyte) {
        $hexbyte = decbin(hexdec($hexbyte));
        $hexbyte = str_pad($hexbyte, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        foreach(str_split($hexbyte) as $bit) {
            $bits[] = $bit;
        }
    }
    return $bits;
}
```

The array should be able to be any length (e.g 3 bits, 8 bits, or 10,000 bits) but could be restricted to only whole bytes if that makes things easier.

Is there a more elegant/efficient way of doing this?

Comment: According to [MySQL pages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html) *The BINARY and VARBINARY types are similar to CHAR and VARCHAR, except that they contain binary strings rather than nonbinary strings.* so a simple   `implode` and `str_split` should work.

Comment: If I do `update table set binfield = '01011101'` (binfield is BINARY 16) I get back `0x30313031313130310000000000000000`

I can do it with `update table set binfield = b'01011101'` but that only solves half the problem, and only for inserting into MySQL. I'd still like to have the binary variable available within PHP.

Comment: Do you only want to convert array of bits `$bits = array(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1);` to `5d`

Comment: No I want to convert it to the binary form for usage elsewhere within the application, and storage in a database. It also needs to be able to hold more than 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function bits2bin($bits) {
    return implode(array_map(function ($v) { return chr(bindec(implode($v))); }, array_chunk($bits,8)));
} //Will return the binary string which corresponds to those bits (hopefully) you can alternatively cast them in MySQL.

function bin2bits($binary) {
       return str_split(base_convert(unpack("H*",$binary)[1],16,2));
}
```

Comment: your bin2bits function is returning an array of 64 zeros for my 16 byte test data - whereas my function returns 128 (with the correct bits as one and zeros). I will look more closely at base_convert as it may help.